# Is it a common bug when using select and adding $options.placeholder and id for custom validation, $invalid is always true?

Tags: angularjs, validation

This is an example file of my HTML:

```
 <form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
      <label> Gender</label> 
      <select name="gender" ng-model="gender" placeholder="Date of Birth - Gender" ng-required="true"> 
           <option value disabled></option>
           <option>Male</option>
           <option>Female</option>
      </select>
      <p ng-show="form.gender.required">required</p>

      <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" placeholder="name">
      <p ng-show="form.name.required">required!</p>
 </form>
```

I have a directive file which automatically adds placeholder and element_id inside of $options and they are in both Input and Select elements. Example in console.log:

```
Gender:  
$option: {
    placeholder: Date of Birth - Gender,
    element_id: RW2D_d2d2asd
},
$valid: false,
$invalid: true,
$dirty: false

name:  
$option: {
    placeholder: name,
    element_id: ODveD_asd83d
},
$valid: true,
$invalid: false,
$dirty: true
```

Its like adding ng-model-options for the elements, but i am doing it in a different way (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions ).

So I selected an item from select, and the error message is still showing.
I typed anything in the input text, the error message disappeared.

Anyone know the reason for select issue with the $options

Comment: you are breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. Primitives don't have inheritance and 2 way binding gets broken as soon as you have child scopes in play. As for the error I suggest you post your directive code

Comment: Yes I get your point, it seems adding something inside $options breaks the golden rule for the select menus

Comment: Without a way to replicate your problem there isn't much way for anyone to help you.

Comment: Well I am currently using http://jonsamwell.com/angularjs-set-default-blur-behaviour-on-ngmodeloptions/ as one of the directives. this is also adding into the select and input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting inside $options, I created a new property object to store the elementID and the placeholder.

Just like what charlietfl said, it is breaking the golden rule of using ng model, which kicks out an error